# read text file line by line and count comparison operators

Tags: c++, file

So for example i have a .txt file with propper c++ code in it. I want to count how many comparison operators (For example !=, <=) have been used. I figured it out how to do it by reading char by char (see code below) but i cannot figure it out how to do it when reading line by line. Maybe someone can give me a hint?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

fstream fin ("file.txt", ios::in);
bool flag=false;
char a;
int count=0;
fin.get(a);

while(fin)
{
    if(!flag)
    {
        if(a=='=' || a=='!' || a=='<' || a=='>')
        {
            flag=true;
        }
    }
    else
    {

        if(a=='=')
        {
            count++;
            flag=false;
        }
        else flag=false;
    }
    fin.get(a);
}
fin.close();
cout<<"The number of comparison operators in this file: "<<count<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of your operators are not characters, like == and <= are two characters so you have to compare them as a string, can you tell me more about your file structure? maybe I can give you a better solution.

Here is a solution you might try

```
void main()
{
fstream fin("file.txt", ios::in);
bool flag = false;
char a;
char b;
int count = 0;
fin.get(a);

while (fin)
{
    if (!flag)
    {
        if (a == '<' || a == '>')
        {
            fin.get(b);
            if (b!='>' && b!='<')
            count++;
        }
        else if (a == '!' || a == '=')
        {
            fin.get(b);
            if (b == '=')
                count++;
        }
    }
    fin.get(a);
}
fin.close();
cout << "The number of comparison operators in this file: " << count << endl;
```

Line by Line Solution

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    fstream fin("file.txt", ios::in);
    string s = "";
    int count = 0;
    while (fin)
    {
        getline(fin, s);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i++)
        {
            if (s[i]== '<' || s[i] == '>')
            {
                if (s[i + 1] != '>' && s[i + 1] != '<' && s[i - 1] != '>' && s[i - 1] != '<')
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            else if (s[i] == '!' || s[i] == '=')
            {
                if (s[i + 1] == '=')
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fin.close();
    cout << "The number of comparison operators in this file: " << count << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: so for example i have such txt file:
`int main()
{

int a;

cin >> a;

if (a==10)
cout << "Bingo!";
if (a<=9 && a>=4)
cout << "Good, but still need some practice!";
if (a <=3 && a >= 1)
cout << "Better luck next time!";
if (a <=0 || a>10)
cout << "invalid input";

return 0;
}`
The output would be : 6 (only counting <=, == and <=)

Comment: Yes this works, but it also reads char by char from a file (`cin.get`). I was wondering, how to read line by line (using  `getline(fin, s)` where s is a string which was read). So i would read a line from the text but i do not know how to compare each word from that line to count those operators?

Comment: For some reason it does not compile. First of all it says that main() must return int value (so it should be `int main()`) but when i change it and try to run this program it crashes. ''program.exe stopped working" But i do not understand why

Comment: Hmm, in this for cycle `for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i++)` i deleted -1 and it started to work.. Can you please explain why you meant s.length()-1 ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no big difference between reading line by line or char by char, you just need two loops, one for reading lines and second for processing that line char by char almost exactly the same way you process the whole file.

Comment: Or maybe one can getline() a whole line and then divide it accordingly? And your answer Isn't solving the actual question. If you just want to tell him that **it's not a big difference** then you should have commented it.